# i can't add value after delete textarea value

Tags: javascript

i have js function that is adding element to textarea.

```js
let article = document.getElementById('article');
function addElement(classname) {
    switch (classname) {
        case 'texttitle':
            let text = '<div classname="texttitle"> \n\t  <a href=""> \n\n\t </a>\n </div>\n';
            article.textContent += text;
            break;
        case 'textvideo':
            let text = '<div classname="textvideo"> \n\t<iframe src=" " allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen=""> \t</iframe>\n</div>\n';
            article.textContent += text;
            break;
        case 'textp':
            let text = '<div classname="textp"> \n\t<p>\n\n\t </p>\n</div>\n';
            article.textContent += text;
            break;
        case 'textimg':
            let text = '<div classname="textimg"> \n\t<img loading="lazy" src="" alt="Error" />\n</div>\n';
            article.textContent += text;
            break;
        case 'textcode':
            let text = '<div class="textcode"> \n\t<pre id="MainContent"> <code class="language-"> </code></pre>\n</div>';
            article.textContent += text;
            break;
        case 'textquote':
            let text = '<div class="textquote"> \n\t<blockquote>\n\t</blockquote>\n</div>';
            article.textContent += text;
            break;
        default:
            article.textContent += '??';
            break;
    }
}
```

```html
<button class="btn btn-dark articletool" type="button" onclick="addElement('textvideo')">video</button>
<button class="btn btn-dark articletool" type="button" onclick="addElement('texttitle')">title</button>
<button class="btn btn-dark articletool" type="button" onclick="addElement('textp')">p</button>
<button class="btn btn-dark articletool" type="button" onclick="addElement('textimg')">img</button>
<button class="btn btn-dark articletool" type="button" onclick="addElement('textcode')">code</button>
<button class="btn btn-dark articletool" type="button" onclick="addElement('textquote')">quote</button>

<textarea id="article" class="form-control" placeholder="Article (optional)" cols="30" rows="10"
          name="article"></textarea>
```

it is adding until delete the textarea value. i mean when i delete the text of textarea

[the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxNjk.png)

after delete. code is working but don't adding value. why?

Comment: Your code is not working. You've declared `text` with `let` numerous times within the same `switch` scope. Also, because you are using `.textContent`, you aren't adding "elements" to the `textarea`, you are just adding unparsed text. If you want actual elements, you need to use `.innerHTML`, which isn't really the best approach either. You really should be using the DOM to create elements and `append()` to inject them into the DOM.

Comment: thanks. i solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you've declared `text` multiple times and used `textContent` instead of `value`, this is working:

```
<button class="btn btn-dark articletool" type="button" onclick="addElement('textvideo')">video</button>
<button class="btn btn-dark articletool" type="button" onclick="addElement('texttitle')">title</button>
<button class="btn btn-dark articletool" type="button" onclick="addElement('textp')">p</button>
<button class="btn btn-dark articletool" type="button" onclick="addElement('textimg')">img</button>
<button class="btn btn-dark articletool" type="button" onclick="addElement('textcode')">code</button>
<button class="btn btn-dark articletool" type="button" onclick="addElement('textquote')">quote</button>

<textarea id="article" class="form-control" placeholder="Article (optional)" cols="30" rows="10"
          name="article"></textarea>
```

```
let article = document.getElementById('article');
function addElement(classname) {
    switch (classname) {
        case 'texttitle':
            article.value +=  '<div classname="texttitle"> \n\t  <a href=""> \n\n\t </a>\n </div>\n';
            break;
        case 'textvideo':
            article.value += '<div classname="textvideo"> \n\t<iframe src=" " allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen=""> \t</iframe>\n</div>\n';;
            break;
        case 'textp': 
            article.value += '<div classname="textp"> \n\t<p>\n\n\t </p>\n</div>\n';
            break;
        case 'textimg':
            article.value += '<div classname="textimg"> \n\t<img loading="lazy" src="" alt="Error" />\n</div>\n';
            break;
        case 'textcode':
            
            article.value += '<div class="textcode"> \n\t<pre id="MainContent"> <code class="language-"> </code></pre>\n</div>';
            break;
        case 'textquote':
           
            article.value += '<div class="textquote"> \n\t<blockquote>\n\t</blockquote>\n</div>';
            break;
        default:
            article.value += '??';
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `value` property instead of textContent for textarea

```js
article.value += text;
```